# SP2010 Unable to open documents in Office Client - 3 authentication prompts followed by 'Could not open..'

Tags: 2010

I am getting three authentication prompts when I try to open a .docx or .xslx document from SharePoint 2010. After the third prompt, I get a message "Could not open [Document Name]"

I tried this on different machines and on different browsers (IE and Firefox) and see the same behavior. I see the same behavior on other sites also. Other users are also seeing the same behavior.

If I download the document, I can open it without any issues. The Web Application IIS authentication setting is NTLM and Client Integration is enabled.

[image]

I see this issue when creating a new document also.

Answer (score 0):

NTLM shouldn't give problem. Try to clear browser history and turn on automatic logon with Current Username and Password" option of browser. Add site to trusted intranet zone

Comment: I have selected Automatic logon with Current User and Password and added site to trusted intranet zone. I dont think this is a browser problem as I am seeing this issue for all users on all browsers on different machines.